# Redirect blog archive into certain format

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, url, url-rewriting

I asked the question in [WPSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOLdu.png) before, but the answer I got so far is a complicated one. I'm actually looking for a `.htaccess` way. Here's what the scenario is:

My blog archive URLs were like:

```
http://example.com/2014/03
```

I changed my site's permalink from `/%postname%/` to `/%postid%/%postname%/`, and using Redirection plugin, I set a redirection like:
[image: redirection 1]

and it's working. But the problem occurs in the archive URLs. The new archive URL generated with a /date/ basename before the dates, like:

```
http://example.com/date/2014/03
```

I'm trying to use the same Redirection plugin to redirect the URL, but failed:
[image: redirection 2]

I then tried writing `.htaccess` on my own (with no `.htaccess` writing experience) with:

```
Redirect permanent http://example.com/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) http://example.com/date/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)
```

with the help of [htaccess editor](http://www.htaccesseditor.com/en.shtml) and [this blog](http://perishablepress.com/redirect-wordpress-date-archives-htaccess/). But failed too.

How can I let my blog not to get 404 on such archive URL? I'm afraid, I'm dumb with rewrite rule till now. :(

### UPDATE

Here's how my `.htaccess` file just now:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And with Liam Sorsby's answer, I tried pasting the code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /date/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

just below the `# END WordPress` once, and then tried again just before # END WordPress. But both time failed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is incomplete. Please ask your entire question here. Do not link to another website with the question text.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a quick test and this should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /date/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

You may also need to exclude this from the redirect to the index.php page by adding

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(date) [NC]
```

so it should look like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(date) [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /date/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Not working. I tried `example.com/2010/10` on the browser after writing my `.htaccess`, it's taking me to 404 page.

Comment: what is the resulting web page?

Comment: I mentioned that, it's taking me to 404 page. The URL is **NOT** changing to `example.com/date/2010/10`

Comment: i can't see any issue with the above rule and i have tested it using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ can you post where you have put the code above so i can take a look? Just a note, i'm try to help, you dont have to bold and capitalise

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: try adding just RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /date/$1/$2 [R=301,L] but make sure it is inside the if statement but at the bottom

Comment: also try adding RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(date) [NC] under the other rewrite conditions

Comment: updated my answer